# Not able to delete blob from Azure storage Account - Azure Function (Java)

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

When I try to delete a blob from an Azure storage account from my Azure Function (Java) the program just hangs on `blob.deleteIfExists();`

When I perform the same operations on a local storage emulator it runs just fine and deletes the blob from the container.

Here is the code that I am using to delete the blob.

```
        // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(System.getenv("STORAGE"));
        
        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
          
        // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("container-name");
            
        // Retrieve reference to a blob named fileName.
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(fileName); 
        context.getLogger().info(blob.getName());

        // Delete the blob.
        blob.deleteIfExists();
```

The line where I have  `context.getLogger().info(blob.getName());` works fine and returns the correct blob but `blob.deleteIfExists();` is just causing the program to hang.

Comment: Do you have permission to delete the blob? I think you can use a SAS token for the specific container.

Comment: @sakulachi8 let me try and see if it works. I am able to delete blobs from the cloud explorer in VS (I don't know if that is related).

Comment: @sakulachi8 where in the code should I put the SAS token? I have checked online and the only references I could find is people wanting to generate tokens.

Comment: you can add it in the connection string,

Comment: @sakulachi8 I tried and it keeps giving me this error, "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage: Storage account connection string for 'STORAGE' is invalid." I tried both the SAS token and URL. However, I am generating the token from the container level, since I am not able to generate one at the storage account level.

Comment: It was a permissions issue after all. I was able to manipulate file in blob storage when the Function app was deployed. The hanging was only when testing locally due to a permissions issue (I assume).

Answer (score 1):

It was a permissions issue when testing locally. When deployed to Azure the blob deletion happened as it should.